# SQL- Get results based on four dependable tables with relations

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, one-to-many

I am trying to write sql query for a problem I am facing, but I can not get my head around it.

- I have `team_member` table with **team_id** and **member_id**.
- `role` table that stores roles with `team_id` (..*name, slug*)
- `team_member_role`  table that is a *many-to-many* relationship
  between *team_member* and *role* (contains **team_member_id** and **role_id**).
- `role_ability` table, which stores **role_id**. (..*action, subject*)

In my code I get only get to work with **member_id** to extract results.

***Use case:***
*I get the **member_id = 1** and need to retrieve all roles with it's abilities of that specific member.*

**Team member**

| id | team_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 3 | 1 |

**Role**

| id | team_id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ROLE_MEMBER | role_member |
| 2 | 2 | ROLE_ADMIN | role_admin |

**Team Member role**

| role_id | team_member_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 92 |
| 2 | 92 |

**Role Ability**

| id | role_id | action | subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | read | workspace_members |
| 2 | 1 | create | workspace_members |
| 3 | 1 | edit | workspace_members |

Can someone please help with the issue. Thanks!

```
SELECT r.*
FROM role r
JOIN team_member_roles tmr ON r.id = team_member_roles.role_id
JOIN role_ability ra ON tmr.role_id = ra.id
```

I am pretty new in writing complex sql queries and I have basic mock up of how it should look and maybe I could get to the result with *team_member_id* and not with `member_id` which I need to use.

The overall result would be like:

| member_id | name | abilities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROLE_MEMBER | read |
|  |  | create |
|  |  | edit |

Comment: Please update your question to show 1) The DDL for all the tables 2) Some sample data for all the tables 3) The result you want to achieve, based on the sample data you've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Your data model looks to be really broken - which is probably making writing this query appear harder than it is - but we'll ignore that for the sake of answering this question).

Try this:

```
SELECT
TM.MEMBER_ID
,R.NAME
,RA.ACTION
FROM TEAM_MEMBER TM
INNER JOIN ROLE R ON TM.TEAM_ID = R.TEAM_ID
INNER JOIN ROLE_ACTION RA ON R.ID = RA.ROLE_ID
```